# Do periodic orbits in n-dimensional systems of autonomous ODEs imply the existence of a fixed point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The motivation for the question is about whether you can have periodic orbits without a stationary point around which to orbit? A weaker (but more formal) statement would be:

Suppose that $\underline{\dot{x}} = f(\underline{x})$ defines an n-dimensional autonomous system of ODEs for $f : [ 0,1 ]^{n} \rightarrow [0,1]^{n}$  with $f_{i}$ polynomial in $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Suppose that there is a periodic orbit that is parameterised by $g : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^{n} ; t \mapsto (g_{1}(t),...,g_{n}(t))$. Does there always exist $\underline{x'}$ such that $f(\underline{x'}) = \underline{0}$ and for all $i \in \{1,...,n \}$ $\min_{t} g_{i}(t) \leq x_{i}' \leq \max_{t} g_{i}(t)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
For the system that I have in mind, a fixed point is one such that: 1) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) = 0$ for $x_{i} \in (0,1)$. 2) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) \leq 0$ for $x_{i} = 0$. 3) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) \geq 0$ for $x_{i} = 1$. Does the statement hold, but with $f(\underline{x'}) = \underline{0}$ replaced with the previous three conditions? Alternatively, does the statement hold with the hypercube replaced with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Note that your weaker statement is false in a very boring manner since you can always warp everything such that the fixed point simply doesn’t lie in your unit hypercube.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you, that is a good point. For the system that I have in mind, a fixed point is one such that: 1) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) = 0$ for $x_{i} \in (0,1)$. 2) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) \leq 0$ for $x_{i} = 0$. 3) $f_{i}(\underline{x}) \geq 0$ for $x_{i} = 1$. I am sorry that I did not mention this. Do you know what the answer is in this case or in the case when the unit hypercube is replaced with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: I should also mention that I can prove it for linear $f_i$, however the proof does not generalise.

Comment: I don't understand how to interpret the additional three conditions in your comment. Could you perhaps try to clarify?

Comment: @HansLundmark These are boundary conditions. For a vector $x$, if $x_{i} = 0$ and $f_{i} \leq 0 $, then, as it is at the boundary of the hypercube, it will not be able to move in this direction. Hence, it will be stationary in this dimension. I am skipping a bit of detail here, and maybe I should have changed the hypercube to be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ instead.

Comment: OK, so the equilibrium is inside the hypercube, and no solutions starting outside the hypercube can enter it? That condition doesn't seem so relevant for the main question, especially considering that for $n \ge 3$ you can have periodic solutions with no equilibrium at all. (I'm thinking of an example with $n=3$, coming from the Hopf fibration, where *all* solution curves are circles, except for one straight line. I can write an answer with the details in case you are interested.)

Comment: Yes please! I would love to know more. That is exactly the type of example that I was hoping for.